# CreatableSelect validation - field cannot be blank

Tags: reactjs, react-select

need help.
How I can add validation to `CreatableSelect` (npm react-select/creatable).

Need to add a validation that the field can not be blank.

Option `required` not work for me.

In my case the field is not bound to the form.